# Java: Create a simple generic method to count after applying filter

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a simple generic method to count the `numbers` after applying the filter based on the provided `predicate`.

```
static int count(Collection < ? extends Number > numbers, Predicate < ? extends Number > predicate) {
  return numbers.stream().filter(predicate).count();
}
```

It gives me the following error:

> incompatible types: Predicate cannot be converted to `Predicate<? super CAP#2>`
>   where CAP#1, CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
>
> CAP#1 extends Number from capture of ? extends Number
>
> CAP#2 extends Number from capture of ? extends Number

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use the wildcard like this, as the second parameter depends on the first one! Your version implies that you want to take a Collection of Apples to then apply a Banana Predicate on that.

In other words: simply declare a not-unkown type parameter; and use that:

```
static <T extends Number> long count(Collection<T> numbers, Predicate <T> predicate) {
```

For the record: `count()` returns a long result; thus I changed the return type accordingly. If that is not what you want, you have to cast to int, but live with the (potential) loss of information.